# Dimensions of bounding box for arbitrary circle sector

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

I need to determine the dimensions of bounding box for arbitrary circle sector as shown in the diagram below.

[image: bounding box of arbitrary circle sector]

Given:
φ = Start angle in the range of 0 ~ 2π
θ = Sweep angle in the range of 0 ~ 2π
r = radius

Determine:
- Width of bounding box (w)
- Height of bounding box (h)
- Coordinates of the circle center (C)

This problem is for on-screen display, so uses screen coordinates.
i.e. x increases to the right, y increases downwards, and positive rotation is clockwise.

As far as I can see, the result will be dependent on which quadrant points A and B fall in relative to each other.
For example if A falls in the **bottom**-right quadrant and B in the **bottom**-left quadrant, then w will be the horizontal distance between A and B.
However if A falls in the **bottom**-right quadrant and B in the **top**-left quadrant, then w will be the horizontal distance between A and C plus the radius of the circle (since the left edge of the bounding box will be tangent to the circle).

My algorithm to solve this seems to be rapidly becoming overly complex.

Is there a simple and efficient way to solve this?

## Edit

Below is the core of the algorithm I've come up with (in JAVA).

If anyone has a more efficient approach than this, please let me know.

```
    // Calculate end angle
    arcAngleEnd = arcAngleStart + arcAngleSweep;

    /**
     * Do all calculations based on a unit circle for the moment.
     * We'll determine the actual radius later.
     **/

    float uLeft, uTop, uRight, uBottom;

    // Calculate arc Start and End unit vector components.
    float uXstart = (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(arcAngleStart));
    float uYstart = (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(arcAngleStart));
    float uXend = (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(arcAngleEnd));
    float uYend = (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(arcAngleEnd));

    // Determine bottom bound
    if ((arcAngleStart <= 90 && arcAngleEnd >= 90) || (arcAngleStart > 90 && arcAngleEnd >= 450)) {

        // Arc crosses the local +y axis
        uBottom = 1;

    } else if (uYstart <=0 && uYend <= 0) {

        // Arc does not extend below the local x axis
        uBottom = 0;

    } else {

        // Bottom bounds will be which ever is greater out of arc start and end points.
        uBottom = Math.max(uYstart, uYend);
    }

    // Determine left bound
    if ((arcAngleStart <= 180 && arcAngleEnd >= 180) || (arcAngleStart > 180 && arcAngleEnd >= 540)) {

        // Arc crosses the local -x axis
        uLeft = -1;

    } else if (uXstart >=0 && uXend >= 0) {

        // Arc does not extend left of the local y axis
        uLeft = 0;

    } else {

        // Left bounds will be which ever is lesser out of arc start and end points.
        uLeft = Math.min(uXstart, uXend);
    }

    // Determine top bound
    if ((arcAngleStart <= 270 && arcAngleEnd >= 270) || (arcAngleStart > 270 && arcAngleEnd >= 630)) {

        // Arc crosses the local -y axis
        uTop = -1;

    } else if (uYstart >=0 && uYend >= 0) {

        // Arc does not extend above the local x axis
        uTop = 0;

    } else {

        // Top bounds will be which ever is lesser out of arc start and end points.
        uTop = Math.min(uYstart, uYend);
    }

    // Determine right bound
    if (arcAngleEnd >= 360) {

        // Arc crosses the local +x axis
        uRight = 1;

    } else if (uXstart <=0 && uXend <= 0) {

        // Arc does not extend right of the local y axis
        uRight = 0;

    } else {

        // Right bounds will be which ever is greater out of arc start and end points.
        uRight = Math.max(uXstart, uXend);
    }
```

Comment: I'd divide the problem into finding the bounding boxes of the part of the sector in each quadrant and then compute their union.

Answer (score 2):

You have six points that might drive the box.  They are $C$, the points where the circle touches the square (except the rightmost), $A$, and $B$.  You have no way to determine $C$ from the radius and angles.  Nothing in your givens locates the shape in your window. We might as well assume $C$ is $(0,0)$  The rightmost point, the greatest $x,$ is either $0$ from $C$, or $r \cos \phi$ from $A$, or $r \cos (\phi + \theta)$ from $B$.  It is probably easiest to compute each of these and take the maximum.  Alternately, you could say it is $0$ if $\frac \pi 2 \le \phi $ and $\phi + \theta \le \frac {3\pi}2$, $r \cos \phi$ if $\phi \le \frac \pi 2$ and $\phi \le 2\pi-\theta - \phi$, where the first assures that the $x$ coordinate of $A$ is positive and the second assures that the $x$ coordinate of $A$ is greater than that of $B$.  You can use similar logic to find the other three edges of the box, then subtract to find the width and height.

Comment: Thanks. Your response gives some good food for thought. I've also been starting my solution with a local coord system centered @ C. The coord system in the diagram centered @ top left of the bounding box is what my final solution should be made relative to after the fact. As I see it, the givens can locate the shape within the window, as the window is simply the bounding box (apologies if wasn't clear in the question). e.g. using local coords @ C, x of left edge of bounding box will either be minimum x of point A and B, or if the arc sweeps across the local -x axis, x of left edge will be -r.

Comment: ... or if both A and B are in +x and the arc does not sweep across the local -x axis, then x of left edge will be 0.

Comment: This is correct.  That is the counterpart to my point about when the right edge will be $0$.  You can find similar conditions for the top or bottom to be $0$.  You can trade off the simplicity of calculating too many points and finding the maximum versus the logic of figuring out which point is bounding based on the angle. The logic will be faster, but a little harder to program.